# MySQL overloading CPU at 100%+

Tags: mysql, performance

My site appears to be getting over 1 million visits today, usually about 20,000 and for me it seems to be near-unresponsive. I've done some sleuthing and optimised Apache, fixed a bug with PHP sessions, but now the problem I have is MySQL is typically using 100%+ CPU.

Server is 32GB of RAM, with about 50% free, no swap, 3.3Ghz CPU, 4 cores, 4 threads.

I've turned off presistent MySQL connections in PHP.

When I run SHOW PROCESSES(); there are only 8 at best and none are stalling.

Most of my tables are MyISAM. Tables that are InnoDB are not used much.

Contents of my.cnf:

```
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Does anyone have any suggestions of commands to run? Setting to change? Which may help.

Or maybe the server just can't handle this much traffic. Though it was fine at 600,000 visits / day.

**UPDATE**

As per this article:

https://o6asan.com/blog-e/2014/07/03/how-to-see-mysql-server-status-by-phpmyadmin/

I went into the phpMyAdmin status panel and started playing with some of the values that were highlighted red. This seemed to help a little bit. However, in my case I think there is little I can do as the server was processing around 500 queries per second. So I will look into turning my html cache on.

Enabling MySQL query caching with 100MB cache has also made a big difference. The site is still slow, but it works on each load, sometimes quickly, sometimes slowly.

Ultimate solution was to cache the entire site, bar a few pages that require dynamism.

Comment: CPU usage means your queries (joins) are producing too much rows, which mysql needs to evaluate. Enable slow query log and look at the problematic queries with tool like `pt-query-digest`

Comment: Also you should have detailed server monitoring setup for such busy site (zabbix for example). Having no graphs means you don't know the basename of what is normal and can't see the trends and/or spikes.

Comment: I've enabled slow query log. There is nothing in it. The whole site is well optimised for query speed.

I have some system monitoring provided by the hosting company. Big spikes on CPU and bandwidth.

Comment: Then decrease the slow query time for example to 0.5s or 0.1s. Even query taking only 0.1s can cause big trouble if it gets executed 100x per second on a busy site.

Comment: OK. I will try that, but as mentioned; SHOW PROCESSLIST show hardly any query activity.

Comment: Do you have ssh access to that server? `mytop` is a nice program. Or also `phpmyadmin` can display near real-time status data - for example number of queries per second executed. https://o6asan.com/blog-e/2014/07/03/how-to-see-mysql-server-status-by-phpmyadmin/

Comment: Yes, I have ssh. I will check out the link.

There is about one query every 10 seconds ending up in slow query log, taking about 0.15 seconds to execute.

Comment: Enlarging query cache may help if particular queries are repeated a lot. You may also want to investigate using something like memcached to do application-side caching of frequent lookups.

Comment: The MySQL query cache is off by default, you will need to turn it on.